# PythonQt doesn't print anything

Tags: python, c++, qt, python-embedding, pythonqt

I'm following the examples at http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/Examples.html, but PythonQt doesn't print anything on the console. I execute a script that just prints `hello`, but nothing gets printed.

```
PythonQt::init();
PythonQtObjectPtr context = PythonQt::self()->getMainModule();
context.evalScript("print 'hello'\n");
```

On the other hand, if I execute it using plain python embedding it works and `hello` is printed:

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("print 'hello'\n");
```

What's interesting is that if I add `PythonQt::init();` before `Py_Initialize();`, nothing gets printed again. So I assume `PythonQt::init();` does something to python's console output. Does it redirect it somehow? How do I make it print?

I'm on Qt 4.8.6, PythonQt 2.1, and Python 2.7.6.

Answer (score 2):

After reading https://sourceforge.net/p/pythonqt/discussion/631393/thread/33ad915c, it seems that `PythonQt::init();` does redirect python output to the PythonQt::pythonStdOut signal.

This is because `PythonQt::init()` declaration sets `RedirectStdOut` by default:

```
static void init(int flags = IgnoreSiteModule | RedirectStdOut, const QByteArray& pythonQtModuleName = QByteArray());
```

So this works now:

```
PythonQt::init(PythonQt::IgnoreSiteModule);
PythonQtObjectPtr context = PythonQt::self()->getMainModule();
context.evalScript("print 'hello'\n");
```

Or alternatively, I could connect the signal:

```
QObject::connect(PythonQt::self(), SIGNAL(pythonStdOut(const QString&)), this, SLOT(Print(const QString&)));
```